# Summary table of numeric and categorical data in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to build a table with descriptive statistics of a dataset that contains both numerical and categorical data. I would like my table to look like this:

[image: Summary table]

The NA cells could be blank, or not appear.

My data looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
      id =  c(1:6),
      country = c("United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom",
                  "Canada", "Canada", "Germany"),
      gender = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male"),
      height = c(1.9, 1.8, 2.0, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1),
      play_basketball = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"),
      stringsAsFactors = TRUE
)
```

The things that I've tried include:

ftable and prop.table can handle the categorical data, but I'm not sure how to drop the "No" column and add the (freq/total):

```
table1 <- ftable(df$country, df$gender, df$play_basketball)
prop.table(table1, 1)
                        No Yes                           
Canada         Female  0.5 0.5
               Male    NaN NaN
Germany        Female  NaN NaN
               Male    0.0 1.0
United Kingdom Female  0.0 1.0
               Male    0.5 0.5
```

On the numeric side, I know how to compute each mean and sd manually, but don't know how to do it so that it can be automated and added to the table:

```
mean(subset(df, country == "United Kingdom" & 
                gender == "Male")$height, na.rm = TRUE)
sd(subset(df, country == "United Kingdom" & 
                gender == "Male")$height, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I'm tagging dplyr because it has gotten me out of trouble before, but I'm not looking for a dplyr-only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::summarise` to get all the summary stats, then `stringr::str_glue` to easily do the formatted strings.

If you break down the calculations you need for the table, for each group there's the mean & SD of height, the count of basketball players, the count of rows total, and the share of basketball / total.

```r
library(dplyr)

calcs <- df %>%
  mutate(gender = forcats::fct_relevel(gender, "Male"),
         country = forcats::fct_relevel(country, "United Kingdom", "Canada")) %>%
  group_by(country, gender) %>%
  summarise(mean_height = round(mean(height, na.rm = T), digits = 2),
            sd_height = round(sd(height, na.rm = T), digits = 2),
            count_bball = sum(play_basketball == "Yes"),
            n = n(),
            share_bball = count_bball / n) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  tidyr::replace_na(list(sd_height = 0))

calcs
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#>   country        gender mean_height sd_height count_bball     n share_bball
#>   <fct>          <fct>        <dbl>     <dbl>       <int> <int>       <dbl>
#> 1 United Kingdom Male          1.95      0.07           1     2         0.5
#> 2 United Kingdom Female        1.8       0              1     1         1  
#> 3 Canada         Female        1.8       0.14           1     2         0.5
#> 4 Germany        Male          2.1       0              1     1         1
```

Then you can glue together formatted strings, drop what you don't need, and optionally put it into a print format. `tidyr::complete` gives you the `NA` values for combinations of groups that aren't in the data.

```r
formatted <- calcs %>%
  mutate(height = stringr::str_glue("{mean_height} ± {scales::percent(sd_height)}"),
         bball = stringr::str_glue("{scales::percent(share_bball, accuracy = 1)} ({count_bball} / {n})")) %>%
  tidyr::complete(country, gender) %>%
  select(country, gender, height, bball)

knitr::kable(formatted)

|country        |gender |height    |bball        |
|:--------------|:------|:---------|:------------|
|United Kingdom |Male   |1.95 ± 7% |50% (1 / 2)  |
|United Kingdom |Female |1.8 ± 0%  |100% (1 / 1) |
|Canada         |Male   |NA        |NA           |
|Canada         |Female |1.8 ± 14% |50% (1 / 2)  |
|Germany        |Male   |2.1 ± 0%  |100% (1 / 1) |
|Germany        |Female |NA        |NA           |
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)


df[,list(
  heightMean = mean(height),
  heightSd = sd(height),
  basketballPlayers = sum(play_basketball == "Yes")/.N),

  by = list(country,gender)]
```